# virtual functions with compile time constants

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates

I will put my question first and add some longer explanation below. I have the following class design which is not working as C++ does not support virtual template methods. I would be happy to learn about alternatives and workarounds to implement this behaviour.

```
class LocalParametersBase
{
public:
  template<unsigned int target>
  virtual double get() const = 0;   //<--- not allowed by C++
};

template<unsigned int... params>
class LocalParameters : public LocalParametersBase
{
public:
  template<unsigned int target>
  double get() const;               //<--- this function should be called
};
```

Using a simple function argument instead of the template parameter is at the moment no alternative for the following reasons:

1. The implementation of this method in the derived class relies on some template meta-programming (using the variadic class template arguments). As far as I know it is not possible to use function arguments (even if they are of constant integral type) as template arguments.
2. The method will be only called with compile-time constants. Performance is crucial in my application and therefore I want to benefit from the calculation at compile time.
3. The common base class is needed (I have left out the rest of the interface for brevity).

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

---

## Update: Motivation

As there were many questions about the motivation for this kind of layout, I'll try to explain it with a simple example. Imagine you want to measure a trajectory in a three-dimensional space, In my specific example these are tracks of charged particles (of fixed mass) in a magnetic field. You *measure* these tracks by sensitive detectors which are approximated as 2D surfaces. At each intersection of a track with a sensitive detector, the trajectory is uniquely identified by 5 parameters:

- two *local* coordinates describing the intersection point of the track with the surface in the *local* coordinate system of the detector surface (that's why the class names are chosen this way),
- two angles specifying the direction of the trajectory,
- one parameter containing the information about the momentum and the electric charge of the particle.

A trajectory is therefore completely identified by a set of five parameters (and the associated surface). However, individual measurements only consist of the first two parameters (the intersection point in the local 2D coordinate system of the surface). These coordinate systems can be of different types (kartesian, cylindrical, spherical etc). So each measurement potentially constraints different parameters out of the full set of 5 parameters (or maybe even non-linear combinations of those). Nevertheless, a fitting algorithm (think of a simple chi2 minimizer for instance) should not depend of the specific type of a measurement. It only needs to calculate residuals. That looks like

```
class LocalParametersBase
{
public:
   virtual double getResidual(const AtsVector& fullParameterSet) const = 0;
};
```

This works fine as each derived class knows how to map the full 5-d parameter set on its local coordinate system and then it can calculate the residuals. I hope this explains a bit why I need a common base class. There are other framework related reasons (such like the existing I/O infrastructure) which you could think of as external constraints. 
You may be wondering that the above example does not require to have the templated `get` method I am asking about. Only the base class is supposed to be exposed to the user. Therefore it would be very confusing if you have a list of `LocalParameterBase` objects and you can fit a trajectory using them. You even can get the values of the measured local parameters. But you can't access the information which values where actually measured (which renders the previous information useless).

I hope this could shed some light on my problem. I appreciate all the comments received so far.

---

For my current project I am writing a class whose main purpose is to act as a wrapper around a sparse vector of fixed size. Instead of storing the whole vector (which is the representation of some system state) my class has a vector of reduced size as member variable (= corresponding to a sub-domain of the total parameter space). I hope the illustration below gives you an idea of what I am trying to describe:

```
VectorType(5) allParameters = {0.5, 2.1, -3.7, 4, 15/9};   //< full parameter space
VectorType(2) subSpace      = {2.1, 4};                    //< sub domain only storing parameters with index 1 and 3
```

In order to be able to make the connection to the original vector, I need to "store" the indexes which are copied to my "shortened" vector. This is achieved using non-type variadic template parameters. I also need to be able to query the value of the parameter with a certain index. This should yield a compile time error in case this parameter is not stored in the "shortened" vector. My simplified code for this looks like:

```
template<unsigned int... index>
class LocalParameters
{
public:
  template<unsigned int target>
  double get() const;

private:
  AtsVectorX m_vValues;
};

LocalParameters<0,1,4> loc;
//< ... do some initialisation ...
loc.get<1>();  //< query value of parameter at index 1
loc.get<2>();  //<-- this should yield a compile time error as the parameter at index 2 is not stored in this local vector class
```

I managed to implement this behaviour using some simple template programming. But other parts of my code need to treat these "shortened" vectors uniformly through one interface. I still want to be able to access through the interface `LocalParametersBase` the information whether a parameter with a specific index is stored (if not I want to get a compile time error), and if yes, I would like to access the value of this parameter. In code this should look similar to

```
LocalParametersBase* pLoc = new LocalParameters<0,1,3>();
pLoc->get<1>();
```

Comment: Overall, I think that templates and virutal functions are basically opposite. templates = compile time polymorpism, virtual functions = runtime polymorphism. trying to combine the two sounds terrible, in my opinion. if you do need that functionality, consider templeting the class itself and not the function.

Comment: I don't quite follow from your explanation, why do you want to use inheritance at all? Are you considering swapping different implementations of your sparse vector that you will only know at run time? You say that other functions want a uniform interface, but a uniform interface to the implementation you've shown, and what else?

Comment: To give a specific example, this line ``pLoc->get<1>`` has serious conceptual problems. You implemented get with integer template parameters for performance reasons and to do stuff at compile time, but you introduce an indirection that cannot be resolved until run time, and is also fairly expensive to boot.

Comment: @DavidHaim I am aware that both concepts serve different purposes. My problem is that I know that the get() function will only be called with compile-time constants and I need to make a comparison with the variadic template arguments of the derived class. To my knowledge this is not possible if I would use `target` as a simple function argument to the get method. Making the base class templated is not an option as for instance I need to be able to store many different instance in a vector.

Comment: @NirFriedman My application is a tracking software. One track can be described by 5 parameters which is the total phase space. Tracks are reconstructed from many measurements but each measurement only adds information for 1 or 2 coordinates. For track reconstruction algorithms I am not interested what are the specific coordinates of an individual measurement (especially because the math is always the same). Therefore I need to have an abstract base class describing "a measurement of some parameters".

Comment: @cgumpert so, again, try putting the `get` parameter as class template value rather than trying to template `get`

Comment: @cgumpert You don't need an abstract base class for that necessarily. I understand you want to separate interface from implementation, but you don't need an interface for that unless you need to choose the implementation at *runtime*. Consider this: ``template <class T> mysort(T& cont) { std::sort(cont.begin(), cont.end()); }. You can call this function with any container that implements begin and end; this is polymorphism as well, just statically (i.e. the container type must be known at compile time).

Comment: @David I am sorry but I do not quite understand this suggestion (I probably should make the description more clear). For one specific instantisation of `LocalParameters` I want to be able to call `get` with different template arguments (see the end of third code snippet). So I do not see how this could be fixed at class level.

Comment: @cgumpert `template <int param> class LocalParametersBase{...}`

Comment: @David This would only allow to query for exactly one parameter. It also adds a template parameter to the base class which I want to avoid (e.g. to be able to store them in vectors).

Comment: @Nir I understand your suggestion and it would probably work for the algorithmic part of the code. However, it is mandatory framework requirement that there is a (template free) base class (in the end we need to store all measurements in some container).

Comment: @cgumpert But your interface is not template free. You wrote ``pLoc->get<1>();`` where ``pLoc`` is a base class pointer. It's still not clear why you even need inheritance at all, why you can't fold LocalParamtersBase and LocalParameters. In addition, your whole optimization of trying to access vector indices by template is very unusual. It's extremely limiting (your vector is never usable with run time integers, ever), and you are trying so hard to avoid a very small performance hit (regular vectors are very fast), while eating a much larger one (virtual function dispatch).

Comment: @cgumpert I think you need to show how and why your client code would actually use your abstract base/uniform interface. So far, I don't see why that's a requirement (and don't believe I'm alone in that).

Comment: I added a section with some more information on the motivation. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A suggestion

Without more information about what you are doing, I am only making educated guesses about what is driving you towards this approach.

A common performance problem with code that depends on a virtual interface is that the framework provides generic functionality that dispatches to the virtual methods at very high frequency. This seems to be the issue that you are facing. You have code that is performing computation on sparse vectors, and you want to provide to it a generic interface representing each sparse vector you happen to create.

```
void compute (LocalParametersBase *lp) {
    // code that makes lots of calls to lp->get<4>()
}
```

However, an alternative approach is to make the computation generic by using a template parameter to represent the derived object type being manipulated.

```
template <typename SPARSE>
void perform_compute (SPARSE *lp) {
    // code that makes lots of calls to lp->get<4>()
}
```

Each `get<>` call in the template version of `compute` is against the derived object. This allows the computation to occur as fast as if you had written code to directly manipulate a `LocalParameters<0,1,4>`, rather than performing a dynamic dispatch per `get<>` call.

If you must allow the framework control when the computation is performed, and so the computation is performed on the base class, the base class version can dispatch to a virtual method.

```
class ComputeBase {
public:
    virtual void perform_compute () = 0;
};

void compute (LocalParametersBase *lp) {
    auto c = dynamic_cast<ComputeBase *>(lp);
    c->perform_compute();
}
```

By using CRTP, you can create a helper class that takes the derived type as a template parameter, and it implements this virtual method by passing in the derived. Thus, the computation only costs one dynamic dispatch, and the rest of the computation is performed on the actual sparse vector itself.

```
template <typename Derived>
class CrtpCompute : public ComputeBase {
    void perform_compute () {
        auto d = static_cast<Derived *>(this);
        perform_compute(d);
    }
};
```

Now your sparse vector derives from this helper class.

```
template <unsigned int... params>
class LocalParameters
    : public LocalParametersBase,
      public CrtpCompute<LocalParameters<params...>> {
public:
    template <unsigned int target> double get() const;
};
```

### Making your interface work the way you have specified it

After the results are computed, you want to place the resulting sparse vector into a container for later retrieval. However, that should no longer be a performance sensitive operation, so you can use the method described below to achieve that.

> Base template method
>  → Base template class virtual method
>  → Derived template method

If you are wish to use polymorphism, then delegate the template method call in the base class to a virtual function. Since it is a template method, the virtual function has to come from a template class. You can use a dynamic cast to get to the corresponding template class instance.

```
template <unsigned int target>
class Target {
public:
    virtual double get() const = 0;
};

class LocalParametersBase {
public:
    virtual ~LocalParametersBase () = default;
    template <unsigned int target> double get() const {
        auto d = dynamic_cast<const Target<target> *>(this);  // XXX nullptr
        return d->get();
    }
};
```

To automate the implementation of the virtual methods for each `Target`, you can again use CRTP, passing in the derived type to the helper. The helper casts to the derived type to invoke the corresponding template method.

```
template <typename, unsigned int...> class CrtpTarget;

template <typename Derived, unsigned int target>
class CrtpTarget<Derived, target> : public Target<target> {
    double get() const {
        auto d = static_cast<const Derived *>(this);
        return d->template get<target>();
    }
};

template <typename Derived, unsigned int target, unsigned int... params>
class CrtpTarget<Derived, target, params...>
    : public CrtpTarget<Derived, target>,
      public CrtpTarget<Derived, params...> {
};
```

And now, you inherit appropriately from your derived class.

```
template <unsigned int... params>
class LocalParameters
    : public LocalParametersBase,
      public CrtpCompute<LocalParameters<params...>>,
      public CrtpTarget<LocalParameters<params...>, params...> {
public:
    template <unsigned int target> double get() const;
};
```

Comment: I don't follow the use of `dynamic_cast` here, and you comment about it. We do know that `this` in `Crtp` is a base of `Derived`, so what is the runtine type check a `static_cast` would miss? Oh, and you should check the pointer for nullptr if you use dynamic cast.

Comment: I thought it would catch a coding error where the wrong type is passed as `Derived`. But, I was thinking of removing it, anyway.

Comment: @jxh many thanks for suggestion and explanation. Your code example solves exactly my problem. I have to admit that it looks more complicated then what I had hoped for. 
Concerning your suggestion I still have a problem/question: at the point where I execute the performance sensitive operations, I only have access to the sparse vectors through a base class pointer ( first all measurements are collected, calibrated and stored in a list of LocalParametersBase pointers, afterwards fitting algorithm is called with this list as input). In this situation the templated compute method wouldn't work?!